# Python ProcessPoolExecutor() not running code in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, process-pool

I am trying to run two separate Python in parallel. To do this I am using the `ProcessPoolExecutor()` from `concurrent.futures` module. I have made two test scripts which I want to run in parallel:

**Script 1:**

```
import time

def run():
    print('starting script 1')
    t = 3
    print(f'Running script 1: Sleeping {t} second(s)')
    time.sleep(t)
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

**Script 2:**

```
import time

def run():
    print('starting script 2')
    t = 4
    print(f'Sleeping {t} second(s)')
    time.sleep(t)
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

These scripts simply sleep for 3 and 4 seconds, respectively. To call these scripts I use the following code:

```
import time
import concurrent.futures
import test_script_1, test_script_2

if __name__ == '__main__':

    start = time.perf_counter()
    print("Starting with scripts execution")
    script_list = ['test_script_1', 'test_script_2']

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for script in script_list:
            executor.map(exec(f'{script}.run()'))



    print('all scripts done')
    finish = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Finished in {round(finish-start,2)} second(s)')
```

All scripts are in the same folder. I would expect these scripts to run in parallel, but they don't. The output I get in my console is the following:

```
Starting with scripts execution
starting script 1
Running script 1: Sleeping 3 second(s)
starting script 2
Sleeping 4 second(s)
all scripts done
Finished in 7.0 second(s)
```

As you can see, the script takes 7 seconds to run in total, rather than the expected 4 seconds. What am I doing wrong?

I tried switching to ThreadPoolExecutor(), which does the exact same thing.

**Update:**

I have implemented the code provided by OM222O:

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as PPE
from os import cpu_count
import test_script_1, test_script_2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.perf_counter()
    print("Starting with scripts execution")
    print("Available CPU cores: ", cpu_count())
    script_list = [test_script_1.run, test_script_2.run]

    with PPE() as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(script) for script in script_list]

    # wait for scripts to finish execution
    # for future in futures:
    #     future.result()

    print('all scripts done')
    finish = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Finished in {(finish - start):.2f} seconds')
```

This seems to be working. The total execution time is 4 seconds. However, the console is not printing the `print()` statements in the individual scripts:

```
Starting with scripts execution
Available CPU cores:  40
all scripts done
Finished in 4.40 seconds
```

If I switch to the `ThreadPoolExecutor()` the script outputs are printed:

```
Starting with scripts execution
Available CPU cores:  40
starting script 1
Running script 1: Sleeping 3 second(s)
starting script 2
Sleeping 4 second(s)
all scripts done
Finished in 4.00 seconds
```

However, since the actual scripts I intend to run in parallel are CPU heavy processes and not I/O processes I would like to use `ProcessPoolExecutor()` and not `ThreadPoolExecutor()`

I am using Spyder 5.4.2, see below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I'm not sure why your code is running for 7 seconds, but you are using `map` incorrectly; the whole point of `map` is to not do `for x in y`, which is exactly what you're doing. I think the way you wrote your code means that it's executing all the scripts (which takes 7 seconds) for every item in the list.
Also check that you actually have multiple cores available, or try passing `os.cpu_count()` to `PPE`, i.e.: `PPE(os.cpu_count())`.

This works for me (I only included main.py since the other modules are easy to copy from the image):

main.py:

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as PPE
from os import cpu_count
from s1 import *
from s2 import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.perf_counter()
    print("Starting with scripts execution")
    print("Available CPU cores: ", cpu_count())
    script_list = [script_1, script_2]

    with PPE() as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(script) for script in script_list]

    # wait for scripts to finish execution
    for future in futures:
        future.result()

    print('all scripts done')
    finish = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Finished in {(finish - start):.2f} seconds')
```

Here are the modules and the results:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Your code does not work if my scripts are externally saved scripts though. If I set `script_list = [test_script_1, test_script_2]` and set `futures = [executor.submit(script.run()) for script in script_list]` the script still runs for 7 seconds.

Comment: @GuidoDeHaan check the updated answer. If it still wasn't working, add the output of the program to the original question.